# In Windows and Linux how to find installed mercurial is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

In both windows and linux how to find installed mercurial is 32 or 64 bit using cmd line ?

hg version doesnt show.

```
C:\Users\dkanagaraj>hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.4.2)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2015 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 1):

On Debian or Ubuntu Linux you can query the "mercurial" package using `dpkg -l mercurial`.

Here is some sample output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  mercurial      2.8.2-1ubunt amd64        easy-to-use, scalable distributed
```

Notice the `amd64`, it shows that it's a 64bit version.

On RedHat or Fedora and other RPM-based distributions the command is probably

```
rpm -qi mercurial
```